# How do I tell Wolfram Alpha that I want the fourth derivative of y in a differential equation?

Tags: wolfram-alpha

For example, how would I enter y^(IV) - 16y = 0?

typing out fourth derivative, and putting four ' marks does not seem to work.

Comment: It seems to work for me?

Comment: Odd. Seems to work for everyone else.

Answer (score 1):

Typing [`y'''' - 16y = 0`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?t=crmtb01&f=ob&i=y%27%27%27%27%20-%2016y%20%3D%200) or [`(d^4/dx^4 y) - 16y = 0`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?t=crmtb01&i=(d%5E4%2Fdx%5E4%20y)%20-%2016y%20%3D%200) both seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Input:

y''''[x]

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y''''(x)+-+16y(x)+%3D+0.

Answer (score 0):

The expression

```
solve y'''' - 16 y = 0 for y
```

seems to work.

[Link to result](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+y%27%27%27%27+-+16+y+%3D+0+for+y).